# Python Pandas: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, pandas, types, datatable, valueerror

I keep getting a value error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '66,790'`

I have a column of incomes in the form £xx,xxx as a string, so I'm converting them to an integer:

`income["Median_2012/13"]=income["Median_2012/13"].str.replace('£','').replace(',','').astype('int64')`

I have no idea why this throws a value error, when I'm removing all the components of the string that stops it from being an integer. £66,790 is the first value in the column. It also fails with "float". Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the comma - `'66,790'`

Comment: that's what .replace(',','') is for no? Not sure why that isn't working

Comment: Because you are not calling `str` before it `income["Median_2012/13"]=income["Median_2012/13"].str.replace('£','').str.replace(',','').astype('int64')`

Comment: yup thats the answer, thanks!

Comment: Avoid to use `str.replace` twice when you can do in one pass.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove all undesired characters with `[£,]`:

```
>>> df['Median_2012/13'].str.replace('[£,]', '', regex=True).astype(int)

0    66790
Name: Median_2012/13, dtype: object
```

But it would be better to use `pd.to_numeric` instead of cast as int because if you have some decimals it will raise an exception:

```
>>> pd.to_numeric(df['Median_2012/13'].str.replace('[£,]', '', regex=True))

0    66790
Name: Median_2012/13, dtype: int64
```